# Open an empty, brand new file in a new Emacs window, from terminal

Tags: init-file, buffers, osx

I work on a Mac 10.9.5 and use Emacs 24.4 (installed with macports).

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778836/customizing-emacs-open-new-files-tabs-and-properly-storing-back-up-files?noredirect=1#comment43984459_27778836 .There I was advised to split the "whole-question" into different questions, and also post it here, so here is the 1st of 3 emacs related questions, , hopefully in a better format and in a more adequate stack exchange.

**open an empty, brand new file in a new Emacs window, from terminal.**

at the moment, when I type in my terminal (or XQuartz), for example:

```
>emacs new.py &
The file ~/new.py does not exist.
```

which, effectively, does not exist, but I would like Emacs to open an empty file called new.py. Of course, I can always get around by typing:

```
>emacs &
```

then start coding and save it as new.py. I simply would like to be able to do that from terminal. Also, once emacs is open, if I type `>emacs&` on terminal, I "land" in the file already open and I have to do : `Cmd-N + C-x C-f` to open a brand new file. So my first question is: Is there something to be added to my .emacs file so I open a brand new file from terminal?

Comment: Do we understand the `emacs &` command the same way? Launch command in [background](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/)?

Comment: It should just work.  When I type `emacs newfile.txt -Q` (the `-Q` to prevent loading the init file to confirm that it's vanilla Emacs), Emacs pops open with a buffer for `newfile.txt`.

Comment: Hi Nsukami. Thanks for answering. Ignore the `&` if you want. Typing `emacs new.py` without the `&` does return the message `new.py does not exist` as well. For example, the fink emacs installation seems to do it by default.

Comment: @Dan, thanks. However, `emacs newfile.txt -Q` returns `open: invalid option -- Q`

Comment: Do you have `emacs` defined as an alias or a shell script? Seems like you are not invoking Emacs directly.

Comment: @glucas yeah!, as an aliased, is aliased to: ` /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` . Is that the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with the way Emacs is being packaged as an OS X GUI app (MacPorts) and called via an alias. I'm not on an OS X machine at the moment but it looks like the arguments you are passing from the shell are being processed by the OS X `open`command rather than Emacs itself.

The wiki page here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc20 suggests that what you want to do is:

```
open -a /Applications/MacPorts?Emacs.app <file-name>
```

A potentially nicer option would be to start the Emacs GUI app and call `(server-start)` (say, in your init file) to start a server. Then you can use `emacsclient` from the shell when you want to open something. Take a look at the [Emacs Server](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html#Emacs-Server) manual page for details.

**EDIT**

For future readers who don't skim the comments below, @Javier solved the problem by defining his own `emacs` alias to call the app directly, e.g. in .tcshr

```
alias emacs  /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

Comment: Hi glucas, thanks for your answer. Still, `open -a /Applications/MacPorts?Emacs.app new.txt` returns `open: No match`, since new.txt does not exist (I want emacs to create it, as if I typed for example, `mvim foo.txt`). I will dig into the `emacsclient` as I have never used it, thanks again.

Comment: Looks like a common question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808201/bash-profile-function-to-open-emacs and the other SO thread it references.

Comment: Thanks for the post, problem solved. I just included in my .tcshr file a direct call to the application: `alias emacs  /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` and it works. Thanks again glucas

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
emacs -a new.py
```

This creates the new file and opens it in Emacs window.

Comment: -a is not a legal option here